# How to use DefinitelyTyped in Angular5?

Tags: google-visualization, angular5, definitelytyped

If I am correct DefinitelyTyped has TypeScript definitions for multiple libraries. In my case I wanted to use Google Charts definitions available [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/be94d35589e92323ab5396637c63819887bdecfa/types/google.visualization/index.d.ts).
I have installed them using

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
npm install --save-dev @types/google-apps-script
```

But I don't know how to import them to my project. I have tried using

```
import { Google } from '@types/google-apps-script';
```

But Visual Studio Code throws an error, that it is not a module and my `declare const google` is still of `:any`, which I want to avoid.

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To get Google Charts to work in my Angular 5 project I used these DefinitelyTyped types instead which is only for the Google Charts JavaScript library.

```
@types/google.visualization
```

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/google.visualization

Here is how I imported the types into an @Injectable Service class. This statement did not raise an error about it not being a module like when I tried to import using *.

```
import { } from 'google.visualization';
```

In the constructor is where you can load the charts library just once and then create your chart functions to pass with data and config options to the callback (setOnLoadCallback).

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
```

I added a script element to index.html to load the 'https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js' but perhaps there is a better way to include external libraries such as this.